# in javascript get the value of a session array

Tags: javascript, php

```
var reserve=prefinishedTask%15;

var num = "<?php echo $_SESSION['picture'][reserve]; ?>";
```

`$_SESSION['picture']` is an array of integers, and I am trying get one of them with index reserve. Currently the code does not work.

If I change it to

```
 var num = "<?php echo $_SESSION['picture'][1]; ?>";
```

it could work, but I need different indexes in the array, so how to fix the code? Best,

Comment: JavaScript and php do NOT run at the same time. Learn about the page life cycle. PHP has finished loaded before the content is sent to the browser.

Comment: @epascarello what does your point have to do with the question? There is nothing really wrong with doing this as far as I understand

Comment: so you mean reserve is a JS var, could not be accessed here? then, how can i fix this problem?

Comment: @MikeMiller `reserve` is a JavaScript variable, OP is trying to use it in the php code. My point is 100% valid.

Comment: Question is terrible though. What do you want to output? Is it the first index in the array? Is so use `reset()` function which will give you first element regardless of key

Comment: @epascerello - Sorry yep your entirely correct. Hadnt spotted that was what was going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `$_SESSION['picture']` into a javascript variable, and get the values via this variable

```
var reserve=prefinishedTask%15;
var sess = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['picture']); ?>");
var num = sess[reserve];
```

Answer (score 7):

Put the entire array into a Javascript variable using `json_encode()`

```
var nums = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['picture']); ?>;
```

Then you can access the array element:

```
var num = nums[reserve];
```